# WinForms: DataGridView with E.F. does not show New Row

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a simple WinForm with a DataGridView that shows record with Entity Framework.
My problem is that New Row feature appears only if the DataGridView is empty.
How is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Luis

PS
Here some details of the WinForm class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GestioneFormazione;

namespace MpFormazione
{
public partial class MpFormazione : Form
{
    public MpFormazione()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.CellClick += DataGridView1_CellClick;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.ButtonColumunIndex)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                
                cliente.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value != null)
                    cliente.Nome = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();                    
                SaveToDb(cliente);
                
            }
        }

        
    }
    private void SaveToDb(Cliente cliente)
    {
        using (var context = new MPFORMAZIONEEntities())
        {
            context.Cliente.Add(cliente);
            context.SaveChanges();                
        }
            

    }
    private void clienteBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
    private void ClienteBindingSource_AddingNew(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventArgs e)
    {            

    }
    private int ButtonColumunIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MpFormazione_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new MPFORMAZIONEEntities())
        {
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = context.Cliente.ToList<Cliente>();                
        }
    }       
}
```

}

The page has only this code, and the Entity Framework for "Cliente" and "Dipendente" entities.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your code

Comment: This is packages.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.it" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>

Comment: I have a problem to insert C# code. 
Even if it's indented correctly, it always tells me that something is wrong

Comment: Edit your question. When typing code, whatever language, start each line of code with four spaces. There is some weird thing happening after bullets. In that case: after bullets add some text (for example a space) before adding code